# Access flask dynamic routes values in jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How can I access dynamic route value, generated by flask, in jinja2 templates?

For example, I have route like this:

```
@bp.route('/<username>')
def index(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    return render_template('index.html', user=user)
```

Jinja2 template:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('index', username=HERE_GOES_DYNAMIC_VALUE) }}">Show user</a>
```

Is it possible to access `username` value from `request` object?

Answer (score 1):

`render_template('index.html', user=user)` makes the `user` variable available to Jinja2 template engine, which is included in Flask by default.

If you want to create a link using the user's username, you can do it like this:

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('index', username=user.username) }}">Show user</a>
```

Flask example:

```py
@app.route('/users')
def users():
    users = User.query.all()
    return render_template('users.html', users=users)
```

Jinja2 loop example (users.html):

```html
{% for user in users %}
<a href="{{ url_for('index', username=user.username) }}">Show user {{ user.username }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is more information about Jinja2 variables: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#variables